NFC Card Reading on Android: Encountering Error 6982
I will authenticate with a Turkish ID card to identify the user in my application. I created the code below for this. My card supports isodep and nfca. I used isodep, but although isodep returns 9000 (successful) as a response, when reading data from the pages, the data comes with 6982. How can I solve this?
private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent
    private lateinit var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "NFC not supported on this device.")
            return
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, javaClass).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        }

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE else 0
        )
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (intent.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED ||
            intent.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED ||
            intent.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
        ) {
            val tag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG, Tag::class.java)
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)
            }
            tag?.let { handleNfcTag(it) }
        }
    }




        private fun handleNfcTag(tag: Tag) {
            val tagId = tag.id
            Log.d(TAG, "NFC Tag ID: ${bytesToHex(tagId)}")

            when {
                IsoDep.get(tag) != null -> handleIsoDep(tag)
                NfcA.get(tag) != null -> handleNfcA(tag)
                MifareClassic.get(tag) != null -> handleMifareClassic(tag)
                else -> Log.d(TAG, "Unsupported tag technology")
            }
        }

    private fun handleIsoDep(tag: Tag) {
        IsoDep.get(tag)?.use { isoDep ->
            try {
                isoDep.connect()
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to IsoDep tag")
                val selectAidCommand = byteArrayOf(0x00.toByte(), 0xA4.toByte(), 0x04.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), 0x07.toByte(), 0xA0.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), 0x02.toByte(), 0x47.toByte(), 0x10.toByte(), 0x01.toByte())
                val response = isoDep.transceive(selectAidCommand)

                readBinaryData(isoDep)
                readRecordData(isoDep)
                Log.d(TAG, "IsoDep Response: ${bytesToHex(response)}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "IsoDep Response: ${bytesToHex(response)}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error communicating with IsoDep tag: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }





    private fun readBinaryData(isoDep: IsoDep) {
        for (i in 0..20) {
            val command = byteArrayOf(0x00.toByte(), 0xB0.toByte(), i.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), 0x10.toByte())
            try {
                val response = isoDep.transceive(command)
                Log.d(TAG, "Read Binary Page $i: ${bytesToHex(response)}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error reading binary page $i: ${e.message}")
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private fun readRecordData(isoDep: IsoDep) {
        for (i in 1..10) { // Try reading first 10 records
            val command = byteArrayOf(0x00.toByte(), 0xB2.toByte(), i.toByte(), 0x04.toByte(), 0x00.toByte())
            try {
                val response = isoDep.transceive(command)
                Log.d(TAG, "Read Record $i: ${bytesToHex(response)}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error reading record $i: ${e.message}")
                break // Stop if we encounter an error
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleNfcA(tag: Tag) {
        NfcA.get(tag)?.use { nfcA ->
            try {
                nfcA.connect()
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to NfcA tag")

                val atqa = nfcA.atqa
                val sak = nfcA.sak
                Log.d(TAG, "NfcA ATQA: ${bytesToHex(atqa)}, SAK: $sak")
                Toast.makeText(this, "NfcA ATQA: ${bytesToHex(atqa)}, SAK: $sak", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error communicating with NfcA tag: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }



    private fun handleMifareClassic(tag: Tag) {
        MifareClassic.get(tag)?.use { mifare ->
            try {
                mifare.connect()
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to MifareClassic tag")

                val type = when (mifare.type) {
                    MifareClassic.TYPE_CLASSIC -> "Classic"
                    MifareClassic.TYPE_PLUS -> "Plus"
                    MifareClassic.TYPE_PRO -> "Pro"
                    else -> "Unknown"
                }
                val sectorCount = mifare.sectorCount
                Log.d(TAG, "MifareClassic Type: $type, Sector Count: $sectorCount")
                Toast.makeText(this, "MifareClassic Type: $type, Sector Count: $sectorCount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error communicating with MifareClassic tag: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun bytesToHex(bytes: ByteArray): String {
        return bytes.joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
    }



    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "NfcReader"
    }

To test whether this problem only occurs with the ID card or not, I tried it with a bank card and had the same problem. I could not find any documentation about it.
Connected to IsoDep tag IsoDep Response: 9000

I never worked with Turkish ID cards, but all the ID cards I used are not readable by simply reading a "page" or similar from the card's memory. They all followed the "MTRD" standard ("Machine Readable Travel Document"). There is a library available for this on Android: https://jmrtd.org/ (JMRTD: An Open Source Java Implementation of Machine Readable Travel Documents)
